# Reload jquery autocomplete in the on change event of a drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have country,state dropdowns and a city textbox with autocomplete feature.My issue is,when I change state, it is displaying previously selected cities since city autocomplete takes data from cache instead of calling server with new stateid.City autocomlete request server response with new stateid only if the cities are not in the selected list.Please give a solution for this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which autocomplete are you using?  The one in UI 1.8 or a third party plugin?

Comment: Iam using jQuery Autocomplete plugin 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to include:

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

in your ajax call. that should solve the cacheing issue.

jim